# Solid.js textarea: detect key or access native keyboard event

Tags: keyboard-events, solid-js

Consider this snippet ([playground](https://playground.solidjs.com/anonymous/d7f1c315-c773-48bb-b6a1-b0c5967e1392)):

```
<textarea onInput={event => {
  console.log(event.key) // TypeScript error and undefined at runtime
  setState(event.currentTarget.value)
}} />
```

I want to detect whether the user pressed enter or shift-enter.

The browser native event has [`key`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/key) and `shiftKey` properties, which are absent on Solid's event. Neither can I find an equivalent to React's `event.nativeEvent` property.

Do I really need to use [useKeyDownEvent](https://primitives.solidjs.community/package/keyboard#usekeydownevent)? That approach seems to suffer from a race condition when using it inside the textarea's `onInput` though...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The input event fires when the value of an `<input>`, `<select>`, or `<textarea>` element has been changed.

Solid does not overwrite events, so your statement about event object with missing properties is not accurate. You should use keydown or keyup event:

> The keydown and keyup events provide a code indicating which key is pressed, while keypress indicates which character was entered. For example, a lowercase "a" will be reported as 65 by keydown and keyup, but as 97 by keypress. An uppercase "A" is reported as 65 by all events.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/keydown_event

There is no race condition but browsers observe specific order when firing events. Events related to keypress comes before changing the value, on input comes after.

Comment: Thanks, you are right! `<textarea onKeyDown={e => e.key} />` even works... seems I've spent too long in React-land to remember the native browser events...

Comment: Okay, the actual solution was a bit more complicated, I wrote it down here: https://github.com/solidjs/solid/discussions/416#discussioncomment-6845759

Comment: Glad you figured out 